# Delete a Missing Case

Tags: civireport, civicase

I ran a Case Detail Report to see a list of cases because my Views table count was not adding up. I realized from this report that there is a case with an "Active" status that does not have a Contact ID. I can't seem to find this case anywhere. The case is not "deleted" from what I can tell. Any ideas is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's weird to see a case without a client. Maybe, it was created correctly and somehow `civicrm_case_contact` table row was deleted for this contact_id?

If you wish to delete this case from your site, you can make use of the API explorer - `http://site-name/civicrm/api#explorer` OR can be navigated through `Support -> Developer -> API Explorer`

Use `Case` Entity with `Delete` action and pass the case id as a parameter -

[image]

If you don't know the case id - you can check by placing your cursor on the subject column of the case detail report. The URL will be shown on the bottom left of your browser which has the `caseId` param as shown in the screenshot -

[image]

Comment: Hovering over the subject for the case ID is a neat trick -- thanks!!